# Namespace package error when installing RAKE in Python

Tags: python, keyword, extract

When I am trying to install [RAKE - Rapid Automatic Keywords Extraction](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rake/1.0) I am getting the following error on both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7:

```
error: Namespace package problem: rake is a namespace package, but its
`__init__.py` does not call declare_namespace()! Please fix it.
(See the setuptools manual under "Namespace Packages" for details.)
```

I have tried installation using `pip` as well as manual installation with `python install setup.py`.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not sure why `rake` doesn't properly call `declare_namespace` as it should (to work with py2.7 and py3.any) -- rather than just hacking a fix yourself you may want to ask the author at https://github.com/fishkao/rake ...

Comment: Good idea, Alex. I've emailed the author and will report back once I get further info...

Comment: take a look at this issue : https://github.com/fishkao/rake/issues/1

Answer (score 9):

I had the above error when trying to install rake with `pip install rake`.  Searching for the proper package name with `pip search rake` gave a list including `python-rake`.  Running the line `pip install python-rake` fixed the error / properly installed rake.

Note the import of rake uses all caps (i.e., `import RAKE`), as shown in the [project's repo](https://github.com/tomaspinho/python-rake).

Comment: I thought for sure my pip installation was broken, getting egg_info errors... nope, just poor-naming convention. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the module is under RAKE as RAKE. I tried the following and it worked.

```
    import RAKE.RAKE as rake

    rake.Rake("path/to/stop/list")
    ...
```